# Start Fragment from Activity or save data and return to previous Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, onitemclicklistener

I am using [nav drawer](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/). So i need from `Fragment` start `Activity` in which i start another `Activity` where i have `ListView`,clicking on which i must save data.

After save i need to return to `Fragment` where saved Data must be showing.
So here is my `Fragment`

```
public class ArmoryFragment extends Fragment {

public ArmoryFragment(){}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_armory, container, false);
    Button button = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button_rifles);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Rifles.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    return rootView;
}
}
```

and here is my activivty from where i need to return

```
public class Rifles extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener, OnItemSelectedListener {
DatabaseHelper db;
String BrandModel;
private RifleDAO rifleDAO;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.rifles);
    initList();
    this.rifleDAO = new RifleDAO(this);

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, riflesList, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, new String[] {"rifle"}, new int[] {android.R.id.text1});
    listView.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                                long id) {
            String item = ((TextView)view).getText().toString();
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            BrandModel= ((TextView)view).getText().toString();
            String[] parts=BrandModel.split(" ");
            String Brand=parts[0];
            String Model = parts[1];
     // need to return from somewhere here

        }

    });
} next is parser code... supose it is not needed
```

So how can I return from `Activity` to `Fragment`?

Comment: ofcourse i have some method to save needed data, i need somehow to start previous Fragment from onItemClick

Answer (score 1):

Well if you want to save data, I prefer adding the data to a table in your database (obviously you have a databaseHelper class so make you own table) and when you are back from your activity put extra a position you want and call :

```
selectItem(mCurrentSelectedPosition);
```

so `mCurrentSelectedPosition` is the position of the fragment that you want to be selected.